# FacesConverter not working with mojarra 2.1.0-b09, 2.1.1-b02?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

---

With this maven dependency, it works :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4-b09</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4-b09</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

---

But with this, it's not working :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <!--  or even this : <version>2.1.0-b09</version> -->
        <version>2.1.1-b02</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <!--  or even this : <version>2.1.0-b09</version> -->
        <version>2.1.1-b02</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

with the exception of

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/primebert] threw exception [Expression Error: 
Named Object: heroConverter not found.] with root cause
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: heroConverter not found.
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:1311)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.ForwardingApplication.createConverter(ForwardingApplication.java:153)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValueHolderRule$LiteralConverterMetadata.applyMetadata(ValueHolderRule.java:85)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate
Impl.java:402)
```

---

And here's my simple converter class :

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter("heroConverter")
public class HeroBeanConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent ui, String newValue) {
        System.out.println("getting as object");
        HeroBean hero = HeroBean.findHeroBeanByName(newValue);
        System.out.println("found hero : " + hero);
        return hero;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        System.out.println("getting as string for value " + value);
        if (value == null) return "";
        return ((HeroBean) value).getName();
    }
}
```

Is it a bug, or im at a mistake here ? :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. It's related to [issue 1937](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1937). This bug causes that JSF annotations aren't been scanned on non-Glassfish containers, because they accidently included some Glassfish-specific annotation scanning code.

The 2.1.1-b02 is also a development build. Rather use the stable builds. The latest stable is 2.0.4-b09.